# Refactor two sub procedures into one and pass parameters as argument

Tags: vba, excel

These are two sub procedures I am refactoring into **one** procedure which will pass parameters through the argument.

```
Sub ImportCNR()

MyPath = Range("b2")                                'Defines cell that contains path to source that have been saved down
Workbooks.Open (MyPath)                             'Opens workbook that have been saved down
Set tempbook = ActiveWorkbook                       'Names  workbook for future closing
LR = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row                  'finds last row in edits



ReDim aCNR(1 To LR, 1 To 4)
cRow = 0


 cName = "Entity ID"
 CA = Cells.Find(What:=UCase(cName), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
 cName = "Share Class"
 cB = Cells.Find(What:=UCase(cName), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
 cName = "Exchange Rate"
 cC = Cells.Find(What:=UCase(cName), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
 cName = "Net Assets"
 cD = Cells.Find(What:=UCase(cName), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column

     For r = 2 To LR
         cRow = cRow + 1
         aCNR(cRow, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(r, CA) 'Fund Number
         aCNR(cRow, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(r, cB) 'class
         aCNR(cRow, 3) = Sheets(1).Cells(r, cD) / Sheets(1).Cells(r, cC) 'TNA


     Next r


tempbook.Close
End Sub

Sub ImportRelationships()

MyPath = Range("b4")                                'Defines cell that contains path
Workbooks.Open (MyPath)                             'Opens workbook that have been saved down
Set tempbook = ActiveWorkbook                       'Names  workbook for future closing
LR = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row                  'finds last row in edits



ReDim aRel(1 To LR, 1 To 4)                         '
rRow = 0


 cName = "Hedge Entity Id"
 CA = Cells.Find(What:=UCase(cName), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
 cName = "entity id"
 cB = Cells.Find(What:=UCase(cName), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column
 cName = "share class"
 cC = Cells.Find(What:=UCase(cName), After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Column

     For r = 2 To LR
         rRow = rRow + 1
         aRel(rRow, 1) = Sheets(1).Cells(r, CA) 'side pocket
         aRel(rRow, 2) = Sheets(1).Cells(r, cB) 'Fund
         aRel(rRow, 3) = Sheets(1).Cells(r, cC) 'class


     Next r


tempbook.Close
End Sub
```

Here is my refactoring so far:

```
Sub testing()
'ImpCNR (b2,"Entity ID", "Share Class","Exchange Rate","Net Assets")
ImpCNR (b2)

End Sub

Sub ImpCNR(cell As String)
'Sub ImpCNR(cell As String, cName1, cName2, cName3 As String, Optional cName4 As String)

Debug.Print (cell)
'Debug.Print (cName1)
'Debug.Print (cName2)

End Sub
```

Why does my `testing` sub fail to print `b2` when I call the `ImpCNR (b2)`?

Comment: Uh `b2` is not defined???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
ImpCNR (b2)
```

To this:

```
ImpCNR "b2"
```

.

And change this:

```
Debug.Print (cell)
```

To this:

```
Debug.Print cell
```

Comment: because *string* variables always need to be passed with "quotes" and the `debug.print` line does not require parenthesis.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman Umm... no. String variables NEVER can be passed with quotes. However, string literals must be. It's not that the Debug.Print does not require parentheses, no sub or method requires parentheses.  The parentheses evaluate the variable prior to the call and the value is passed not the variable.

Comment: Thanks Excel Hero - I see where I should have been more clear, you need to pass a string argument with quotes, unless it's a variable that is already defined as a string. I was just trying to add some substance so the OP knew *why* he needed the syntax in the way that you provided it for him.

Comment: How do I pass the array into the argument? My two arrays are `aCNR` and `aRel`

Comment: @phillipsK You just pass them after they have been defined and populated. So if your `ImpCNR` routine was defined to accept three parameters, the cell address and also the two arrays, then you would do it like this: `ImpCNR "b2", aCNR, aRel`